# Define key to toggle between javascript implementation and test file

Tags: files, projectile, javascript

I have been trying to set up a shortcut for jumping between a JavaScript implementation and test. I have particular requirements that are making examples I see harder to apply.

I currently work with *many* very small javascript projects. The structure of the project normally has its tests in a mirrored directory structure (like so: )

`lib/foo.js
lib/someDir/bar.js
test/fooSpec.js
test/someDir/barSpec.js`

So the spec files are not in the same directory, as the implementation

I first was looking at examples for `ff-find-other-file`, but they were for situations when the files were located in the same directories. I'm looking to configure it a little more dynamically (walking up the directory tree until lib, then adding a similar path with test replacing lib)

I also know projectile has a function for doing just this. I use projectile in my setup, but when attempting to use its built in method (C-c p t) I get the message "Project type not supported!". Interestingly enough, projectile is able to list all my test files via (C-c p T). 
Is there way of configuring projectile for javascript, so that it knows how to find a corresponding spec file?

I also saw the project [toggle test](https://github.com/rags/toggle-test), but am looking for a more automatic solution. It requires a configuration for each project to enable toggling between tests. This is rather inconvenient to me because when working with Node/JS I bounce between many projects (it's very common to divide an application into many very small projects with their own tests). I also often look at external dependencies, and then their specs. More often then not they have this structure. Having to configure toggle test each time I need to use this feature makes it not very useful.

Comment: Projectile has the command projectile-find-other-file that works the same as ff-find-other-file, except that it lists all possible other files in your project. You can custom with projectile-other-file-alist variable,

Comment: FWIW, the `ff-search-directories` variable provides limited functionality for finding files in other directories (albeit not arbitrary directory walking). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660637/smarter-ff-find-other-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about projectile, but if I needed something like what you described, I'd possibly go with something like this:

```
(defun jump-to-test ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file-other-window
   (cl-loop with parts = (reverse (split-string (buffer-file-name) "/"))
            with fname = (file-name-sans-extension (cl-first parts))
            for (name . rest) on (cl-rest parts)
            until (string-equal name "lib")
            collect name into names
            finally (cl-return
                     (mapconcat 'identity
                                (nconc (reverse rest)
                                       (list "test")
                                       (reverse names)
                                       (list (format "%sSpec.js" fname))) "/")))))
```

Comment: thanks, this is nearly exactly what i'm looking for. And is educating me on elisp. I made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mikedmcfarland/ea661781d7028e9a2e22) containing the opposite side (jump to implementation from test). How about a means to determine which path structure I'm currently in, so that I can call the appropriate function using the same keystroke

Comment: never-mind, updated the gist containing the function. Thanks for the help. You've made my day!

Comment: @MikeMcFarland ha! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Tweaked wvxvw's answer to provide it as a toggle between files. It also doesn't open it in a new window.

```
(defun js-jump-to (current from to format-name)
  (find-file
   (cl-loop with parts = (reverse current)
            with fname = (file-name-sans-extension (cl-first parts))
            for (name . rest) on (cl-rest parts)
            until (string-equal name from)
            collect name into names
            finally (cl-return
                     (mapconcat 'identity
                                (nconc (reverse rest)
                                       (list to)
                                       (reverse names)
                                       (list (funcall format-name fname) )) "/" )))))

(defun js-format-impl-name (fname)
  (format "%s.js" (replace-regexp-in-string "Spec" "" fname)))

(defun js-format-test-name (fname)
  (format "%sSpec.js" fname))

(defun js-jump-to-implementation-or-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current (split-string (buffer-file-name) "/")))
    (cond
     ((member "test" current) (js-jump-to current "test" "lib" 'js-format-impl-name))
     ((member "lib" current)  (js-jump-to current "lib" "test" 'js-format-test-name))
     (t (error "not within a test or lib directory"))
  )))
```